# Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'col' - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2016

I have data like this in one of my columns: I have around 100k records like this.

```
            tele
            ---------

            C12345
            75784329899(c)
            75678934729(cell)
            ygasd786782399
            guisahkl#57812897
            5476783-6779834
```

I have written this code to remove all alphabets and keep the number only. Which is working fine.

```
            create TABLE #TEMP
            (
            id [int] NOT NULL,
            tele [char](14),
            col [bigint] NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
            )
            ;with cte as (select top (100) N = row_number() over

            (order by @@spid) from sys.all_columns),

            data as(

            select id,tele,col

                from table1` 
                cross apply (
                    select (select C + ''
                        from (select N, substring( tele,N,1) C from cte where N <= datalength(tele)) [1]
                        where C between '0' and '9'
                        order by N
                        for xml path(''))
                        ) P(col)

                    where p.col is not null
```

----------------Insert into temp table---------------------------------------

```
            INSERT INTO #TEMP (id,tele,col) 
            SELECT id,tele,cast(col as bigint) 
            FROM data 



            tele
            ---------

            12345
            75784329899
            75678934729
            786782399
            57812897
            54767836779834
```

However, now I wanted to keep all the cell number and remove the junk only(or unknown chars)
and my result should be like this:

```
                tele                           col
            -----------------------------------------------------

            C12345                          C12345
            75784329899(c)                  75784329899(c)
            75678934729(cell)               75678934729(cell)
            ygasd786782399                  786782399
            guisahkl#57812897               57812897
            5476783-6779834                 54767836779834
```

I have modified the code as beloew:

```
            create TABLE #TEMP
            (
            id [int] NOT NULL,
            tele [char](14),
            col [bigint] NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
            )
            ;with cte as (select top (100) N = row_number() over

            (order by @@spid) from sys.all_columns),

            data as(

            select id,tele,col

                from table1` 
                cross apply (
                    select (select C + ''
                        from (select N, substring( tele,N,1) C from cte where N <= datalength(tele)) [1]
                        where C between '0' and '9'
                        order by N
                        for xml path(''))
                        ) P(col)

                    where p.col is not null AND

                      col NOT LIKE '%(CELL)%' 
                      OR col NOT LIKE  '%CELL%' OR col NOT LIKE '%(C)%'
                      OR col NOT LIKE '%C%' OR col NOT LIKE  '%MOBILE%'
                      OR col NOT LIKE  '%X%' OR col NOT LIKE '%EXT%'
                      OR col NOT LIKE '%XT%' OR col NOT LIKE '%EX%' 
                      OR col NOT LIKE '%/%' OR col NOT LIKE '%,%'
                               )
```

----------------Insert into temp table---------------------------------------

```
            INSERT INTO #TEMP (id,tele,col) 
            SELECT id,tele,cast(col as bigint) 
            FROM data
```

However, its showing me this error:

```
        Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'col', table 'tempdb.dbo.#TEMP_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________000000000125';
        column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

How should I correct this?
 Please help. Thanks.

Comment: you have insert null in the col column but you create the table null not accepted.So that error occurred

Answer (score 0):

Remove NOT NULL constraint in CREATE statement of tempory table for column col.

Comment: Thanks for the clue. However, I would like to achieve little different. Could you please revisit the question?

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove NOT NULL constraint from the table creation.
2. If you do not want to allow NULL then change the `INSERT` as below
   `ISNULL(cast(col as bigint), '')`:

Query:

```
  INSERT INTO #TEMP (id,tele,col) 
  SELECT id,tele,ISNULL(cast(col as bigint), '')
  FROM data
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try Like this 
 INSERT INTO #TEMP (id,tele,col) 
            SELECT id,tele,CAST( ISNULL(col,'') as BigInt)
            FROM data